# What is needed to run secure web sockets on https?

Tags: javascript, https, websocket, ssl-certificate

I would like to run secure web-sockets that are needed for an HTTPS I am running on my tomcat server, I know they are declared with `wss`. However do I need to do anything else besides declaring web-sockets with `wss` to get secure web-sockets to run correctly, or is that suffice for running secure web-sockets with no errors such as with certificates or handshakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a self signed certificate, you need to put that certificate for HTTPS as well, so the browser can prompt the user to accept the certificate. Otherwise it will fail to establish the WSS:// connection.

Also, connect using the hostname provided in the certificate, not the ip address.

Comment: Can you give me a good resource that outlines this process of creating a self signed certificate that also does HTTPS?